# Solve binary expression tree for given variable

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

For the expression:

```
res = ((v + 10) * (i - 2)) / 3
```

My program builds the following binary tree:

```
(=)
 ├─ (res)
 └─ (/) 
     ├─ (3) 
     └─ (*) 
         ├─ (+)
         │   ├─ (v)
         │   └─ (10)
         └─ (-)
             ├─ (i)
             └─ (2)
```

To obtain a solution for variable `v`, I manually solve it like this:

```
((v + 10) * (i - 2)) / 3 = res
(v + 10) * (i - 2) = res * 3
v + 10 = (res * 3) / (i - 2)
v = ((res * 3) / (i - 2)) - 10
```

How can I programmatically do the same operation?

For example, given the binary tree and its specific node (in this case `v`), rebuild this tree so that it evaluates to that node:

```
(=)
 ├─ (v) <-- my node
 └─ (-)
     ├─ (10)
     └─ (/)
         ├─ ...
         └─ ...
```

Comment: Step 1: find a good book on symbolic algebraic solvers.

Comment: If i=2 then any v is a solution if res ==0, otherwise there are no solutions. Even if i != 2 there might be many solutions in integers because integer division is not 1-1, eg 0/3 = 1/3 = 2/3 = 0

Comment: Hope that v only appears in one place.

Comment: Your original tree is not consistent with the expression. For instance: in the expression `3` is the second operand of the `/` operator, yet it is the first child of the `/` node. On the other hand,  in the expression, `(i - 2)` is the  second operand of the `*` operator, and it is also the second child of the `*` node. But then, in the *result* tree, we see `10` as the first child of the `-` node, ...etc. It is not consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some comments on the input/output:

The first operand of an operator should consistently be a *left* child in the tree representation, while the second operand should be a *right* child.

So, since `3` is a divisor (and thus the second operand of a division), it should occur in the input tree as a *second* child. So the input tree for `res = ((v + 10) * (i - 2)) / 3` should be:

```
(=)
 ├─ (res)
 └─ (/)
     ├─ (*)
     │   ├─ (+)
     │   │   ├─ (v)
     │   │   └─ (10)
     │   └─ (-)
     │       ├─ (i)
     │       └─ (2)
     └─ (3)
```

Similarly, the output should have `10` as the second child of the `-` node:

```
(=)
 ├─ (v)
 └─ (-)
     ├─ (/)
     │   ├─ (*)
     │   │   ├─ (3)
     │   │   └─ (res)
     │   └─ (-)
     │       ├─ (i)
     │       └─ (2)
     └─ (10)
```

Some (other) assumptions:

- The root should have `=` as symbol, and have two children.
- The target symbol (here "v") should only occur once.
- The non-root operators should be `+`, `-`, `*` or `/`, and should be nodes with two children (binary).
- Non-operator nodes should be leaves.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript, which defines a `Node` class, including the method that will mutate its subtrees so to bring the target node at left side of the equation and all the rest at the right side:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(symbol, left=null, right=null) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    toString() {
        return !this.left && !this.right ? "(" + this.symbol + ")"
            : "(" + this.symbol + ")\n"
            + " ├─ " + this.left.toString().replace(/\n/g, "\n │  ") + "\n"
            + " └─ " + this.right.toString().replace(/\n/g, "\n    ");
    }
    markPathTo(target, found=false) {
        if (this.left) this.left.markPathTo(target, found);
        if (this.right) this.right.markPathTo(target, found);
        if (this.mark) {
            if (found) throw "symbol (" + target + ") occurs more than once";
            found = true;
        }
        this.mark = this.symbol == target || this.left && this.left.mark || this.right && this.right.mark;
    }
    resolve(target) {
        if (this.symbol != "=") throw "Can only resolve an equality, not (" + symbol  + ")";
        this.markPathTo(target);
        if (!this.mark) throw "Could not find symbol (" + target + ")";
        // Make sure the target is in the left subtree
        if (!this.left.mark) {
            // swap sides of equation
            [this.left, this.right] = [this.right, this.left];
        }
        let operators = {
            "+": "-",
            "-": "+",
            "*": "/",
            "/": "*"
        };
        let op = this.left.symbol;
        while (op !== target) {
            if (!(op in operators)) throw "Unsupported operator (" + op + ")";
            let toMove = this.left.left.mark ? this.left.right : this.left.left;
            if (op === "+" || op === "*" || this.left.right.mark) {
                this.right = new Node(operators[op], this.right, toMove);
            } else {
                this.right = new Node(op, toMove, this.right);
            }
            this.left = this.left.left.mark ? this.left.left : this.left.right;
            op = this.left.symbol;
        }
    }
}

// Demo tree from question (with corrected position of 3)
let tree = new Node("=",
    new Node("res"),
    new Node("/",
        new Node("*",
            new Node("+",
                new Node("v"),
                new Node(10)
            ),
            new Node("-",
                new Node("i"),
                new Node(2)
            )
        ),
        new Node(3)
    )
);

// Display the input tree
console.log(tree.toString());

// Apply the algorithm
tree.resolve("v");

// Display the resulting tree
console.log(tree.toString());
```

Of course, this could be extended to deal with more scenarios, like exponentiation, multiple occurrences of the target symbol, where polynomials are resolved, ...etc. This is however beyond the scope of the question.